# Why in a stack, the priority of each inserted element is monotonically increasing and not strictly increasing?

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue, priority-queue

It is said everywhere that "*In a stack, the priority of each inserted element is monotonically increasing*"
But in stack, every new element has a priority higher than the previous element. So, when implemented as Priority Queue, if 2 subsequent elements have same priority (*as per the definition of monotonic*), the deletion will not adhere to Stack's LIFO policy but FIFO policy.

Shouldn't the **priority** be strictly increasing?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe "monotonically" rather than "strictly" is incorrect.

Monotonically increasing *could* work for a stack if you assume that, between two elements with the same priority, the one inserted earlier will always be after the other. But this assumption isn't made in a literature I've seen on the subject, and will need to be swapped around to simulate a queue (the one inserted earlier will need to be *before* the other).